# Google Cloud Bigtable and Java 8

Tags: java, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm connecting to Bigtable from local machine, following [this example](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-simple-cli).
When I'm running my project using JDK 7 everything works perfect, but when running it with JDK 8 I have following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to create table 'testTable'
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BigtableAdmin.createTable(BigtableAdmin.java:306)
at com.zoomdata.thrift.provider.BigTableTestConnector.testConnection(BigTableTestConnector.java:62)
at com.zoomdata.thrift.provider.BigTableTestConnector.main(BigTableTestConnector.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.getRawHostnameSE()Ljava/lang/String;
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.getKickstartMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:1294)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Handshaker.java:1014)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1475)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1282)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1257)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:222)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:76)
at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:53)
at io.grpc.auth.ClientAuthInterceptor$1.checkedStart(ClientAuthInterceptor.java:82)
at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$CheckedForwardingCall.start(ClientInterceptors.java:185)
at io.grpc.stub.Calls.asyncServerStreamingCall(Calls.java:174)
at io.grpc.stub.Calls.unaryFutureCall(Calls.java:86)
at io.grpc.stub.Calls.blockingUnaryCall(Calls.java:129)
at com.google.bigtable.admin.table.v1.BigtableTableServiceGrpc$BigtableTableServiceBlockingStub.createTable(BigtableTableServiceGrpc.java:332)
at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableAdminGrpcClient.createTable(BigtableAdminGrpcClient.java:78)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.BigtableAdmin.createTable(BigtableAdmin.java:304)
... 7 more
```

Seems there is changes in sun libraries in java 8. Is there a workaround to run this code under java 8?

Comment: I tried Java8 this afternoon -- there is something broken there, I had suggested putting the correct ALPN-boot jar, but that isn't enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HBase hasn't yet been certified to run with Java 8.  For the time being, stick with Java 7.  Here are two HBase / Hadoop tracking bugs for this:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-11090
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-7608

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this while looking for the answer for it myself.

I was able to get it to work with using [right version](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/alpn-chapter.html) of ALPN in my bootclasspath.

For Java 8 I used ALPN version `8.1.4.v20150727`.